# Thread code not work properly without Thread.sleep(...) call

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {
    public int ThrCount    = 0;

    public void ThrCountIncr() {
        while (true) {
            ThrCount++;
            System.out.println(ThrCount);
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (ThrCount > 10) {
                System.out.println(ThrCount + "\n Thread finished");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I remove this line from `run`, it stops working:

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
```

First, I start the thread, then I use `ThrCountIncr`.

```
ThreadTest Thrtest = new ThreadTest();
Thread thr = new Thread(Thrtest);
thr.start();
Thrtest.ThrCountIncr();
```

The thread checks the `ThrCount` variable value, and if it is greater than 10, it stops the program. Without `sleep(100)`, the thread doesn't stop the program, and I think it doesn't check the variable value. Why does the call to `sleep` make this code work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even with the `Thread.sleep()` it might not work. This is because you don't properly synchronize accesses to the shared `ThrCount` variable.

If you make that variable `volatile`, you should not see any issues any longer. However it might not loop exactly 10 times as the `++` operation is not atomic.

Ideally, you should use an AtomicInteger and use its `incrementAndGet()` method.

Also note:

- Java naming conventions: variables and method names should start in lower case (`thrCount`, `thrCountIncr()`
- `sleep` is a static method so you can simply call `Thread.sleep(...);` and it will sleep in the current thread.

Comment: I understand. It's only for my experiments. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If your thread doesn't sleep, other threads may not be able to work, so the the loop inside `ThrCountIncr` may get stuck at any time (probably at its first `sleep` or at the `println`).

**Never have a thread looping without any kind of sleep or wait.**

Note also that `ThrCount++;` may fail if you don't protect it using a synchronization, as it's not an atomic operation.

Comment: thr.start() runs in a different thread and returns immediately... I don't think what you describe can happen.

Comment: thanks for answer, so second thread eat all processor time fo this process.

Answer (score 3):

When a loop has iterated more than 10,000 times it can be optimised by the JIT.  In the case of the second thread, the code for the thread doesn't modify the field so the JIT can either optimise away the `if` condition or determine it is always run.

If you make the field `volatile` this prevents the JIT making such optimisations.

Comment: 10.000 times? Really? Do you have a source? I wonder why it´s not 5.000, or 100.000.

Comment: `-XX:CompileThreshold=10000` from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html